# Cell Statistics calculation in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster-calculator, calculate-values, cell-size, cell-statistics

[Cell Statistics in ArcGIS](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/cell-statistics.htm) will calculate the mean (or statistic of choice) among multiple rasters on a cell-by-call basis.

Can QGIS do this and, if so, how?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [r.series](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/r.series.html) GRASS command in QGIS to accomplish this.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Since QGIS version 3.16, the **cell statistics algorithm** is be available as direct port of the ArcGIS cell statistics tool available. It is implemented in **C++** for optimal performance and can cope with different sources of raster layers. For all the details you can visit the [documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/rasteranalysis.html?highlight=cell%20statistics#cell-statistics).