# Merging overlapping rasters - retaining maximum value using gdal

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, gdal, gdal-merge

I have multiple overlapping tiffs(having 3 bands) which i want to merge using gdal/pyqgis but want to retain the maximum pixel values for the overlapping part. I tried using gdal_merge.py but it only returns the copy of the first tiff of the list I provided (link to this solution i found [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/236746/calling-gdal-merge-into-python-script))
The first image is the two overlapping tiffs
[image: Overlapping tiffs]
The other picture is the result i got from gdal_merge.py
[image: result]

```
import osgeo_utils.gdal_merge
output_file_path = r'insert path here'
input_files_path = r'insert path here'
parameters = ['', '-o', output_file_path] + input_files_path + ['-separate', '-co', 'COMPRESS=LZW']
osgeo_utils.gdal_merge.main(parameters)
```

Code for reference

Comment: Does it have to be GDAL? Have a look at this post https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/89962/cell-statistics-calculation-in-qgis about overlaying rasters to obtain a statistical value, in your case the statistic would be *maximum*.

Comment: Thank you this works

Comment: Does the images overlay exactly or is there an offset between the images as per the example in the question?