# Creating rasters in batch from Boolean operation on previous raster in python

Tags: python, raster, gdal, raster-calculator, rasterio

I intend to create rasters that has values either 0 or 1, depending on the values of the previous rasters. I have a monthly set of rasters for daily albedo, from which if the values are between 0.6 to 0.9 for snow, output on raster is 1 and if not, 0. I've loaded up the rasters from drive but I'm not sure where to go from there.

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/gdrive')
%cd /gdrive

trinf = glob(r'/content/drive/MyDrive/albedo')
```

Comment: Have a read of https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/89962/cell-statistics-calculation-in-qgis and see if that suits your needs.

Comment: What do you mean by "I've loaded up the rasters from drive but I'm not sure where to go from there."? From the code snippet it looks like you have just created a list of the image file names.